# How to remove axis, and other information from Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, jqchart

I need to draw a line graph, but just a line graph with no axes, values​​, etc. Only the graph and percentage at the end.

Q: how to remove all the items from the graph, indicate the axes, axes, etc. you only need to leave a line graph and interest.

```
$('#audience').jqChart({
                legend: { visible: false },
                border: { visible: false },
                title:
                {
                    text: 'Chart Title',
                    font: '12px sans-serif',
                    lineWidth: 1,
//                    strokeStyle: 'black',
                    fillStyle: 'white'
                },
                animation: { duration: 1 },
                series: [
                    {
                        pointWidth: 0.2,
                        type: 'bar',
                        fillStyle: '#7fbbe5',
                        data: [['A', 33]],
                        labels: {
                            stringFormat: ' %s %%',
                            valueType: 'dataValue',
                            font: '11px sans-serif',
                            fillStyle: 'white'
                        },
                        tickOptions: {
                            showGridline: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        pointWidth: 0.2,
                        type: 'bar',
                        fillStyle: '#92b5c7',
                        data: [['A', 67]],
                        tickOptions: {
                            showGridline: false
                        },
                        labels: {
                            stringFormat: ' %s %%',
                            valueType: 'dataValue',
                            font: '11px sans-serif',
                            fillStyle: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

I have an image, where I show, what I have, And what I need:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2h3x3yx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can splice the jqChart Axes -

```
 var axes = $('#jqChartDiv').jqChart('option', 'axes');
//remove all series
axes.splice(0, axes.length );
```